# Circle and line diagram tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles, line

I saw [this](https://stanford.edu/~xing/Stat243/slides_02_bin_model.pdf) diagram [image]

I wonder how we type this up in Latex. I have seen that TikZ package produces similar outcome(?)

Comment: So far I only understood how to draw circle and lines. Could not add labels nor connect them.

Comment: Please add that as code example (MWE).

Comment: Your observation is correct! You can draw this as three (growing right), as automaton or as simple image of three circle connected bylines. Maybe for star you look in http://www.texample.net/. There is a lot of examples of TikZ pictures.

Comment: I have found this one, as almost the thing I wanted. Now I would like to add circles around text... which I have no idea how.

Comment: Then you should simply post some code...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with `pst-tree` (can be compiled with `pdflatex` , with switch `--enable-write18 under MiKTeX,`-shell-escape` under TeX Live and MacTeX):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\psset{shortput=tab, labelsep=0pt}
\MakeShortTnput{\tnput}
$ \begin{psmatrix}
        \pstree[treemode=R, arrows=->, arrowinset=0]{%
            \Tcircle{\mathsf{S₁}}\tnput[labelsep=24pt]{\mathsf{t = 0}}}%
        {%
            \Tcircle{\mathsf{S₃}}^{\mathsf{p}}
            \Tcircle{\mathsf{S₂}}\tnput[labelsep=5pt, tnpos=b]{\mathsf{t = dt}}_{\mathsf{1-p}}}%
    \end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]